# How do we say when opponent's reaction is absurdly bigger than my action

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A stole B's 1 dollar so that for a revenge, B broke A's car of 1000 dollars. Hence A say angrily

> "Absolutely, this is not a necessary condition for my stealing that you broke my car !"

I wanna rewrite this sentence without losing meaning and furthermore, it will be great that the resulting sentence contains something like **don't have to do**, **correspondence**, or **react**.

The followings are my trials :

Your correspondence is really deviating common sense even though I made a mistake.

Comment: "Correspondence" doesn't make sense in this situation. The way you've used it, it looks like it means "a postal letter or email."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to "overreacting", suggested above, you can also use "out of proportion" or "not proportionate". A synonym for the last one is "disproportionate".

"Shooting someone is not a proportionate response to littering!"

"Breaking my car is completely out of proportion to the ding I gave yours!"

"Your response is disproportionate to my offense!"

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disproportionate

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proportionate

While this defines it as a specific meaning of "proportional" (and it is being used that way), English idiom uses "proportionate" instead of "proportional" in cases of the action/reaction or a sense of justice.

To go with your final example, "Your reaction was nonsensical, and completely disproportionate."

Answer (score 1):

That’s called **overreacting**, as defined by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/overreact):

> respond more emotionally or forcibly than is justified.

You can also use the corresponding noun, **overreaction**.

Your suggested sentence is ungrammatical and difficult to understand. My suggestion for what A should say angrily:

> Breaking my car was a complete overreaction to me stealing!